# android device monitor does no respond after clicked in android studio tools>android device monitor

Tags: android

I am facing a problem which is cannot open android device monitor. I wanted to open it in order to export databases updated. Anyone got idea regarding this?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances running?

Comment: @ImAtWar no, Im only running one project

Comment: Is your android studio running in administrative mode?

Comment: @AbdulKawee yup, i tried ady, still the same

Comment: okay and whats in your monitor.ini file, under tools/lib/monitor?

Comment: @AbdulKawee is it this path ? C:\Users\commauser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\lib\monitor-x86

Comment: @zhanweiyap yes ,whats written in this file?

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-data
@noDefault
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145519/discussion-between-abdul-kawee-and-zhanwei-yap).